# SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "object"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

Please help me to understand what's wrong.
I want to parse JSON reply as object.

PHP process.php code:

```
<?php
    $return = array();
        array_push($return['amount']="$amount");
        array_push($return['fee']="$fee");
        array_push($return['total']="$total");
    echo json_encode($return);
?>
```

Returns JSON string:

```
{"amount":"350","fee":"0","total":"350"}
```

JS (jquery) code:

```
$.getJSON("process.php?amount="+amount, function(data,status) {
   var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
   alert (obj.amount);
});
```

I receive error:

> SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "object"

BUT! When I try to insert result instead data (but insert ' quotes left/right):

```
var obj = $.parseJSON('{"amount":"350","fee":"0","total":"350"}');
```

And I see alert = 350. So, it's working good.

I try to make something like that:

```
var jsonreply = "'"+data+"'";
var obj = $.parseJSON(jsonreply);
```

But received below error:

> SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Single quotes (') are not allowed in
>   JSON

Comment: when datatype is json recieved in jQuery ajax methods you don't need to use `$.parseJSON` on reponse, it has already been converted internally. To prove this try `console.log( $.type(data))` in your success callback

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`getJSON` parses the JSON for you — calling `$.parseJSON` will convert the object into the string `[object Object]` and then try to parse that, giving you an error. Just omit the `$.parseJSON` call and use `data` directly.

---

Furthermore, I should note that the calls to `array_push` are strange and unnecessary. [`array_push`](https://www.php.net/array_push) usually takes an array and a value to push on to it, but (for example) in your first line you're setting `$return['amount']` to `"$amount"` and then passing `$return['amount']` to `array_push`, which does nothing at best and might give you a warning or error at worst. You'd get the exact same behavior if you did this:

```
$return['amount']="$amount";
$return['fee']="$fee";
$return['total']="$total";
```

Then you might also realize that the quotes around, say, `"$amount"` are unnecessary, and you could actually do this:

```
$return['amount']=$amount;
$return['fee']=$fee;
$return['total']=$total;
```

Finally, you can actually condense all five lines using some special `array` syntax very easily:

```
echo json_encode(array(
    'amount' => $amount,
    'fee' => $fee,
    'total' => $total
));
```

This is quite a bit nicer if I do say so myself.

Comment: Also, why are you using array_push in your PHP script? If you would like to add values to an array, you can do so more easily like so:

    `$return['amount']=$amount;`

Comment: @mazinsights: Your comment might better belong on the question myself, as I wasn't the one who wrote the code in the first place! It's a good suggestion, though, so I've added that (and a bit more, actually) to my answer.

Comment: In example above I make a simple code. Really, I used array, but when I array_push one array to another I received not good results for json. Something like ["0",{"key0":"value","key1":"value"},{"key0":"value"}]

Answer (score 1):

Actually u dont need to parse it.  U can directly access it

```
$.getJSON("process.php?amount="+amount, function(data,status) {
 alert (data.amount); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your error is here:

```
var jsonreply = "'"+data+"'";
```

Try to escape those ' with "\".
Like

```
var jsonreply = "\'"+data+"\'";
```

Comment: `'` is not a special character within double quotes; backslashing it won't do anything. Perhaps you meant `"\\'"`, but then you're still generating invalid JSON.